# Need to match a value from another table in c#

Tags: c#

I have a table called HoldingBucket and i need to be able to look up to see if an Account name matches one entered in a request table when a class called initalcheck is running in my project.

in short, if value is present in holdingbucket i will code it to do something otherwise the code will continue to run

if request.accountname = (a record in the holding bucket) then .....

but i dont know how to get to a match

Sorry new to this and trying to learn and not seeming to fins an answer on this anywhere that i can apply

Started with this but guessing its way off

```
var InBucket = (from HB in _context.HoldingBucket
                where HB.AccountName == Request.Account_Name
                select HB);


if (InBucket != null)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: what kind of table? A SQL database table? a HTML table? A DataTable object in C#? Please be clear what your data structure is and also what the field you're interested in is called. Thanks. Also I edited your tags - the Visual Studio tag, as the tag blurb says, is for questions about VS features specifically, not for questions about code which you happen to editing using VS.

Comment: apologies, this is in visual studio and a data connection to a sql table

Comment: The field in both tables im trying to match via the class is accountname
holdingbucket.accountname and request.accountname

Comment: ok well you could write a SQL query with a `WHERE` clause to see if there are any rows with a matching account name.

Comment: The answer to this question largely depends on how you are interacting with your data.  Are you using ADO.NET, Entity Framework, Dapper, etc.?

Comment: @Mark Visual Studio and C# are very different things. You can even create C# applications without Visual Studio, for example. Visual Studio is the name of the editor. As for your question, without some code to show how you're already working with your database, it's a little difficult to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're performing this check in a separate class and not a Controller you could do something like this:

```
using System.Linq;

var isAMatch = _context.HoldingBucket.Any(x => x.AccountName.ToLower() == Request.Account_Name.ToLower());

// _context is what you provided me in the comments as your connection string variable

// isAMatch will either be true or false

if(isAMatch) // if there is a match
    doSomething();
else // if there is no match
    doSomethingElse();
```

This is just a simple way, but dependency injection is preferred.

> **If you are using Entity Framework, then you should use the LINQ method called `Any`.  This method returns a boolean value indicating if a condition is met when dealing with a collection of objects.  Basically, the above line is saying "If ANY AccountName in the HoldingBucket table matches request.AccountName then return true, otherwise return false"**

[Information on Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx)

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: He might not know where `Any()` comes from...  Refs! :)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the above, i am using entity framework and i get the following issues, db does not exist in current context. probably a really noobish thing

Comment: @DanRayson I added references, I just wanted to get my answer out there and then I edit to give the most information as possible

Comment: @Mark - it sounds like you need to go over your context class for Entity Framework and confirm that all of your connection strings are set correctly and that you can communicate between app/database.

Comment: @Mark at the top of your controller, do you have a line that looks similar to this? `private ConnectionStringName db = new ConnectionStringName();`?

Comment: @awh112 no that error just means there's no variable called `db` declared in the current scope. Probably OP called their db object something else, or forgot to declare it.

Comment: @ADyson exactly.  probably just under a different variable name

Comment: In the controller for the request (requestcontroller.cs) but not in the class where i was doing the matching

Comment: @ADyson yep - you're absolutely right, how did I miss a null reference error?  :)

Comment: @awh112 it's not a null reference error either, that's a _runtime_ error which may occur when a variable is null and you try to use in a particular way (e.g. access a property from an object which is null). This problem is a _compile time_ error because the variable was never declared (e.g. with `var db....`etc), or perhaps it was declared but not in the scope where it's being used.

Comment: Okay, so you're doing this check in a separate class and NOT a controller, right?

Comment: @ADyson Makes perfect sense; thanks for the clarification.  I'll stop now and avoid butchering terminology even further.  :)

Comment: Okay, well what I provided should be good to go for you.  I can edit my answer further to kind of match what you have, if you could edit your question and post the code that you're currently using.

Comment: had tried something like this but guess i'm way off. picking up as someone has left, not my strong point but always willing to try

var InBucket = (from HB in _context.HoldingBucket
                              where HB.AccountName == Request.Account_Name
                              select HB);
            

            if (InBucket != null)
            {
            do something
            }

Comment: @Mark updated my answer based on what you gave me, seems you don't need the `using` statement since you clearly don't use it in the code you provided

Comment: @M12Bennett YOU ARE AWESOME. thankyou so much, made my day... week no year. i can apply this to so much more now